# ¿Como abrir dos enlaces a través de un mismo enlace en php?

Tags: php, enlace

Quiero abrir dos enlaces a través un de un link, uno que se abra en la misma pestaña y el otro que se abra en otra pestaña.

**Tiene que funcionar en php, tengan en cuenta lo de las comillas.**

Muchas gracias.

```html
else if ($quediaes=="Tue" && 13 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
  echo '<center><h3>Ahora EN VIVO:  <a href="link 1" > UN PARTIDO - </a></h3></center>';
}
```

Comment: Pues vaya, con que ánimos preguntas; te recomiendo quitar esa aclaración porque creo que la misma comunidad se encarga de moderar las preguntas y respuestas, por lo que si hay una respuesta fuera de lugar, será borrada.

Comment: Hola, cálmate tranquilo, te ayudo, pero antes edita la pregunta por favor, no pongas cosas como `POR FAVOR NO ME PEGUEN CODIGOS DE OTRAS PAGINAS`, si se da el caso las van a eliminar.

Comment: Ok, perdón, pero ya me pasó de que me quieran ayudar para quedar bien y me pegen codigos de otras paginas/foros.

Comment: no te preocupes, solo reportalos y ya, por otra parte¿y los links que quieres que se abran son iguales o distintos? puedes hacerlo con js y html

Comment: Pero lo puedo incluir adentro de PHP? Por que si queda afuera de PHP no sería tan automatico, es un texto cuando hay partido.

Comment: que tal, te sirvieron las respuestas?

Comment: Si, ya funciona, no respondí porque me tuve que ir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que intentas hacer depende del frontend de tu sitio, así que lo puedes lograr usando la función [window.open()](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_open.asp) de javascript, dentro de tu código php:

```
else if ($quediaes=="Tue" && 13 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
echo '<center>
    <h3>Ahora EN VIVO: 
      <a href="#" 
         onclick="window.open( \'https://www.tulink_1.com\', \'_self\');
                  window.open( \'https://www.tulink_2.com\', \'_blank\');" >
      UN PARTIDO
      </a>
    </h3>
    </center>';
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Era eso, me sirvió perfecto, perdón en contestar, es que me tuve que ir, muchas gracias, anda justo como quería.

Comment: Genial, marcala como correcta para que así podamos ayudar a otros ;). Saludos

Comment: ok, donde la marco como resuelta?
Y otra cosa, antes de cerrar, quiero conectarla a una base de datos, lo edito aca o creo otro tema para que sea mas claro?

Comment: Debes colocarla en otra pregunta

Answer (score 0):

debes saber que no abres las paginas en PHP, de esto se encarga el código HTML, y una etiqueta  solo puede tener un href asociado, lo que puedes hacer es añadirle además un evento onclick que abra la otar pagina que quieras abrir

```
else if ($quediaes=="Tue" && 13 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
  echo '<center><h3>Ahora EN VIVO: <a onclick="window.open(\'link_nueva_pestaña\', \'_blank\');" href="link 1" > UN PARTIDO - </a></h3> 
 </center>';
}
```

Igual puedes separar los string y concatenarlos para no tener \ escapando caracteres y hacer el código más amigable.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tambien me funcionó como quería.
Se agradece.